# twitter - no mention no retweet

Tags: twitter

I am using a twitter account only to transfer the tweets i entered into another web-site. However, I don't want others to mention me or re-tweet my tweets. The messages I write and the message of those I follow are automatically transferred into my web-site. Therefore, I want others to send tweets because some people might abuse my account or enter undesirable tweets.

So, is there way to prevent all people from mentioning or re-tweeting? My account is protected but that does not help me completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant avoid mentioning, users cant retweet you if your acount is private but thats all you can do.

You can check this page to see if they offer something more like what you need to do.

https://ifttt.com/

Comment: Thank you. Tweets from people I do not follow are not transferred into my web-site. So, if i be careful of people i follow, i think i might be O.K.